# Корректна ли структура сайта одним файлом HTML + PHP?

Tags: php, cms, html

Доброго времени суток, мастера. Пробую изучать PHP, сильно не ругайте, делаю свою CMS для небольшого проекта, приведу код:

```
index.php

<html>
<head><title> Мой заголовок </title></head>
<body>

<div class="логотип">
<?
/* тут php код ищущий в базе jpg логотипа */
?>
</div>

<div class="главное меню">
<?
/* тут php код ищущий в базе ссылки главного меню, формата:
   index.php?page=главная       
   index.php?page=контакт
   index.php?page=о_фирме
*/
?>
</div>

<div class="тело страницы">
<?
/* тут php код ищущий в базе тело страницы 
   если GET($page) не существует, тогда $page=главная 
   если GET($page) == "главная", тогда поиск в базе текста #главной, print ("текст");
   если GET($page) == "контакт", тогда поиск в базе текста #контакт, print ("текст");
   если GET($page) == "о_фирме", тогда поиск в базе текста #о_фирме, print ("текст");
*/
?>
</div>

</body></html>
```

И хотелось бы советов от опытных гуру:

**- Насколько корректна такая <<система>>, какие подводные камни?**

P.S. читал про Smarty, хочется попробовать своим методом

Comment: Если поступать совсем хорошо - посмотрите Code Igninter. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter . Реализация через MVC. Там и посмотрите, что да как

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку буду изучать, но для начала хотелось бы всю структуру понять самому и не вставлять чужой код (читайте, фреймворки). От этого и спрашиваю корректно ли и какие подводные камни, мб так делать глупо в силу неизвестных мне причин, или скажем нагружает сервер.

Comment: >Пробую изучать PHP, сильно не ругайте, делаю свою CMS

все как обычно - "ничего не знаю, но пишу операционную систему с нуля")))

Comment: А вы не хотите изучить PHP создавая поисковик или соц сеть? А то вон и Google и FaceBook вчера новичками были

Comment: А логотип у вас будет менятся часто так же как и у Google? Они ведь дудл каждый раз меняют?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответьте себе на эти **вопросы**:

- что будет, если новую страницу надо будет сделать отличной по структуре?
- где будет происходить подключение к БД?
- если будут входящие данные, то кто и где будет их проверять и обрабатывать?

Я вам скажу, что **это не правильная структура**. Вы не сможете понять никакой "всей структуры" делая вот это. Изучите готовые решения и потом можете пытаться сделать лучше. Сейчас же вы движетесь либо вовсе не в ту сторону, либо будете идти еще очень долго туда, куда все уже пришли.

**Подводные камни**: это нерасширяемо и неподдерживаемо.

**Однако**, если ваш сайт состоит и будет состоять из 3х однотипных страниц, то от такого решения вы только выиграете.

*Логотип в БД? Он правда так часто будет меняться?*

Comment: Поддерживаю ответ, добавлю лишь, что урлы продуманы ужасно с точки зрения СЕО - главная должна открываться только по корню, да и использовать русские символы в URL не желательно. Плюс в структуре явно нет страницы 404, что опять же не очень хорошо отразится на индексации.